# Is there an idiomatic way to prevent recursive function calls in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, function, recursion

Say I have some complicated function that, through subsequent nested function calls, can potentially call itself, is there an accepted method to prevent this recursive call in the case where it is undesirable?

e.g.:

```js
function h()
{
  if(someOtherState)
    f(); // uh-oh
}

function g()
{
  if(someState)
    h();
}

function f()
{
  g();
}
```

Comment: No chance refactoring out the circular dependency is an option, right?

Comment: Yeah, assume that's more complicated/impossible/time consuming than it's worth, versus just dealing with it post-hoc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Invoking Cunningham's Law here (I am not really a JS developer), a way I've found that works is:

```js
function f()
{
  if(f.inFunction)
    return;

  f.inFunction = true;
  // Some complicated/non-deterministic code that may call f() again
  f.inFunction = false;
}
```

Comment: Probably a good idea to wrap that in `try/catch/finally` so that the switch isn't inadvertently left `true`.

Comment: Also, if the code is written to expect that a recursive call will actually *do* something, I'm not sure how this helps. It might be better to throw an exception and move the test that realizes the code is in an invalid state closer to the origin.

Comment: Ah good point with the exception catching...